# MariaDB, what is the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY 1,2'?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm working to write a MariaDB query and am running into the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY 1,2
       ) x
       ) z
 WHERE user_period != 0
 ORDER BY 1,2
-- {"us' at line 42
```

Here is the query:

```
WITH 

users AS (
  SELECT id,
         onboarded_at
    FROM users
   WHERE onboarded_at <= NOW()
   GROUP BY 1
),

events AS (
  SELECT receiver_id,
         type,
         created_at
    FROM events 
   WHERE created_at <= NOW()
)
SELECT *
  FROM (
SELECT *,
       MAX(CASE WHEN user_period = 0 THEN retained_users ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY "Signup Date") AS "New Users",

       retained_users/
          MAX(CASE WHEN user_period = 0 THEN retained_users ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY "Signup Date") AS retention_rate,

       (LAG(retained_users) OVER (PARTITION BY "Signup Date" ORDER BY "Signup Date") - retained_users)/
          MAX(CASE WHEN user_period = 0 THEN retained_users ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY "Signup Date") AS churn_rate,

       (LAG(retained_users) OVER (PARTITION BY "Signup Date" ORDER BY "Signup Date") - retained_users)/
          LAG(retained_users) OVER (PARTITION BY "Signup Date" ORDER BY "Signup Date") AS churn_rate_from_previous_period
  FROM (

SELECT (MONTH,u.onboarded_at) AS "Signup Date",
       (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.created_at) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM u.onboarded_at)) * 12 + 
       (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.created_at) - EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.onboarded_at)) - 
       CASE WHEN (CEILING(DATE_PART('day',f.created_at) - DATE_PART('day',u.onboarded_at))) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS user_period,
       COUNT(DISTINCT f.receiver_id) AS retained_users
  FROM users u
  JOIN events f
    ON e.receiver_id = u.id
 WHERE u.onboarded_at >= DATE_TRUNC(MONTH,NOW()) - INTERVAL '25 MONTH'
 GROUP BY 1,2
       ) x
       ) z
 WHERE user_period != 0
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

The SQL error isn't helpful; what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually with this part of the query:

```
INTERVAL '25 MONTH'
```

the correct form for this is

```
INTERVAL 25 MONTH
```

Another issue is that MariaDB doesn't have a `DATE_TRUNC` function, so it is assuming that it is a user defined function with parameters `MONTH` and `NOW()`. Since `MONTH` is unquoted, it is assuming that is a column name, hence you will get an unknown column error. To resolve this, you can replace the

```
DATE_TRUNC(MONTH,NOW())
```

with

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
```

Also, since MariaDB doesn't have a `DATE_PART` function, you will need to replace

```
DATE_PART('day', expression)
```

with

```
DAY(expression)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just made the update, now I get a different error `Unknown column 'MONTH' in 'field list'`

Comment: Nice, that solved that,,, now it is erroring with `FUNCTION DATE_PART does not exist`

Comment: @AnApprentice no worries. Glad to help.